# 'Evernote 4.5.7 'Could not connect to server' error

Tags: wine, evernote

I've installed evernote 4.5.7 with Wine 1.4, but when I start the Evernote application, a small dialogue appears saying:

> Could not connect to server.
>
> You need to be online to register or perform an initial sync. Please
>   check your internet connection.

But which internet connection? I **am** connected to the internet. Do I need to install a browser in Wine to connect to the internet? I don't understand.

Comment: @manuzhang: no that doesn't help at all sadly. The problem I have is a bit different. I don't even get the login screen. Just a dialogue box with the message, and then the app quits.

Comment: http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30598 This may not solve your problem but just knowing you are not alone could give you some comfort. P.S. I'm using Debian 6.0 and come across the same problem so Ubuntu 12.04 is not to blame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I uninstalled and purged Wine and any associated apps from my system (including winetricks), and instead installed playonlinux. With this, a default Wine system is installed, but you can also install other Wine versions. I chose to install Wine 1.4, and then I installed Evernote 4.5.7 using the Wine 1.4 version. Evernote installed quickly, and now runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Or just install the new Ubuntu [Evernote aka everpad](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/meet-everpad-evernote-unity-lens-enabled-desktop-integrated-client-ppa-available)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, though it didn't work directly for me it helped me to get evernote to run properly on 12.04.

It took me a while to work out, so hopefully this step-by-step will help someone else:

1. Install playonlinux (apt-get)
2. Download  Evernote version 4.0.0.2880 (http://www.filehippo.com/download_evernote/8600/) (couldn't seem to get the latest version to work)
3. Tools-> Manage Wine Versions
4. Install x86 version of 1.5.5
5. Click install
6. List item
7. in the bottom left click "Install a non-listed program"
8. "Install a program in a new virtual drive"
9. Check "Use another version of wine" and "Configure Wine"
10. On the Wine configuration window change Windows version to Windows 7 (Windows XP didn't work for me for some reason)
11. On the other window select version 1.5.5, next
12. Select another file, next
13. Select the install file, run it
14. After you have signed in restart your computer (I had a weird bug that stopped the 'a' key from working until I restarted)